# android action bar size height is too much larger and showing different in mobile and emulator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing android app and I used simple custom action bar. In my toolbar I added Logo pic using `setLogo()` method but my logo size is too large so I got too much height of the action bar. In my android Studio emulator it display perfect with small size action bar but in my android mobile phone I got too large action bar.

Emulator running on Lolipop (API Level 21) and my android mobile working on Kitkat.

[image: In my android mobile phone i getting action bar like this]
but in android emulator it display perfect 
[image: In Emulator it look like this]

my code:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  " + currentChatContact.getName());
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("  last seen at 26/05/2015, 05:15 ");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.boy_thumbnail);
```

my toolbar code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/defaultPrimaryColor">  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am using AppCompat:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/defaultPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>
</style>
```

I have not decided any height of image for action bar but I am getting very large image in a mobile as shown in the image.

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: please review my answer @Kalpesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your tool bar remove the height `wrap_content` and put like this

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

**UPDATE**

Try like this

```
Drawable logo=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy_thumbnail);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(logo);

        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != null)
                if (child.getClass() == ImageView.class) {
                    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) child;
                    if ( iv2.getDrawable() == logo ) {
                        iv2.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: it works fine but now my logo is come into action bar center and title and subtitle is gone

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: Thank you, it's worked, please see this pic: http://s1.postimg.org/fl3o1z3cv/Screenshot_2015_05_27_19_40_23.png

Comment: But it looks like ugly, Please help me to do it some cool, i want some space around image and my Title and Subtitle is large, It is possible to marquee it. Please help to looks good action bar, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Replace your toolbar code with this one

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Comment: sorry @NarenderNishad i tried your code but i can not get what i want youe code give me same input that my code is already gave me